# How can I keep my model files from being refreshed when doing an "Update Model from Database"?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

I have a project that uses Entity Framework Database First style development. I made some changes to various Model files, and now every time I do an "Update Model from Database" on my EDMX file, those changes get wiped out. I see there is a tab for Refresh and it has my model files listed, but there is no way to tell VS to not refresh these files. What should I do here? Thanks.

Comment: Don't write your changes directly to the .edmx classes. Those classes are generated by ef.  The generated classes are defined as partial so that you can define your own partial class in a separate physical file to extend the generated functionality

Answer (score 2):

Don't write your changes directly to the .edmx classes. Those classes are generated by ef. The generated classes are defined as partial so that you can define your own partial class in a separate physical file to extend the generated functionality.

Here's a good example

https://dotnetcodr.com/2015/02/18/extending-class-definitions-with-partial-classes-in-c-net/

It even states at the top of the generated .cs file

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//    This code was generated from a template.
//
//    Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//    Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you changed. If you made changes in the edmx model they will be overwritten every time you re-generate your model.

If you made changes in the generated poco-classes it depends.
Poco's are generated as partial classes. Just create a sub folder and extend your poco's in a separate file with the same class signature.

Same applies to the model context class (yourModelName.Context.cs).  Changes should also be done in a separate file.

Maybe you should try 'Code First from database'. This generates a Fluent model which is much easier to change to your particular needs. No graphic representation of the model though.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said...its DatabaseFirst... so your models file will update from database(not any where else ...not you) .and you should not do it... because every changes will be lose when you update your model from database again! ...if you are change your model for some reason like adding column or(...) you have to do it from your database not here!...but if you changing it for another reasons like adding validation attributes or.. you have to use partial classes!! not writing directly in your model files.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with me, simple solution save all model .cs file in other location after refresh, copy pest the required files

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).