# Should I modify Entity Framework generated classes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have generated my data model from database using Entity Framework, but there are some minor style-related things I'd like to change. For example:

```
public Nullable<int> eventId { get; set; }
```

this is a part of the generated C# code, and I'd like to, let's say, change the property name to `EventId`.

I'm just wondering if doing this in an EF environment is safe, or if it will backfire later and punch me in the face...

Comment: Autogenerated classes should never be manually modified. Exclude them from style checking instead.

Comment: What is the name of the column in the database? eventId or EventId?

Comment: Creating the partial class in which add a new property EventId with get and set works on eventId.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I keep my model files from being refreshed when doing an "Update Model from Database"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44975441/how-can-i-keep-my-model-files-from-being-refreshed-when-doing-an-update-model-f)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were to auto-generate the classes again in the future, your changes would be lost. This has happened to me with a production piece of software where I appended a computed property into a generated class:

`public string GetOtherProps => $"{this.prop1}, {this.prop2}";`

and then referenced that throughout our application.

The classes were regenerated for some reason and suddenly there's hundreds of `Unknown Reference Errors` throughout our software.

Comment: Yup, a point made to me by my manager when the bug hit. Took a little while to figure out that the classes had regenerated because it obviously wasn't a problem locally where they hadnt :)

Comment: Frankly, I'm a bit surprised that is is seen as a valid answer. In fact you're saying: "I also ignored the warnings in the first lines of the generated file, I still edited the code and then got into trouble". Your case is different and the resolution is different. You should have added a partial class. OP should edit the property name in the EDMX.

Comment: @GertArnold I said that I did what OP is intending to do, and it was wrong. It was wrong because I ignored the warnings, the warnings that OP is also ignoring and is asking this question about. I provided an example as to why you *shouldn't* ignore these warnings, and what happens when you do. No need to be condescending.

Comment: @GertArnold Good points, but you could just post them as actual answer if you know what to specifically edit to override the default generated names in a valid way.